# HIDS agent on Chrome OS

Tags: linux, security, google-chrome-os

Does anybody know if there are any HIDS agent applications that support Chrome OS?

OSSEC says that it supports "ALL" linux distros, but as chrome os is so customized, I am not sure if it is possible to install linux applications?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After much headache and dead ends, I was successfully able to compile and run OSSEC on a arm based chromebook running in dev mode.

I completed this with the help of the crouton chroot environment.